# Providing a parameter from an Observable to a function that returns an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, behaviorsubject

I have a function with the following signature:

`fetchUserCar(userId: string): Observable<Car>`

But to get the `userId` parameter, I have to call a function that I cannot edit, which is the following:

```js
private user$ = new ReplaySubject < User > ();
public getUser(): Observable < User > {
  return this.user$.asObservable().share();
}
```

How do I go about in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `getUser()` and then `flatMap` the call to `fetchUserCar` passing the user id obtained from `getUser()`.

```
fetchCar(): Observable<Car> {
    this.userService.getUser()
        .flatMap(user => this.carService.fetchUserCar(user.id))
}
```